# how can I get list of revisions of file from webdav repository on client side

Tags: java, webdav, jackrabbit

I'm getting list of files via PropFindMethod:

```
DavMethod pFind = new PropFindMethod(url, DavConstants.PROPFIND_ALL_PROP, DavConstants.DEPTH_1);
httpClient.executeMethod(pFind);
MultiStatus multiStatus = pFind.getResponseBodyAsMultiStatus();
MultiStatusResponse[] responses = multiStatus.getResponses();
for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    DavPropertySet properties = responses[i].getProperties(200);
    //...
}
```

but `properties` does't contain any information about revisions of resource.
How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live DeltaV properties are not reported with PROPFIND allprop, see [RFC 3253](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3253.html). You probably need the properties DAV:checked-in, DAV:checked-out, and DAV:version-history, or the DAV:version-history report.

Comment: how can i get this properties in terms of jackrabbit api?

Comment: I guess you need a different propFindType, and supply a DavPropertyNameSet.